# Doctrine attributes namespace

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces

trying to understand what is the Doctrine. I using PHPStorm 2016.3.2 and plugin "PHP Annotations".

When i'm create the Model i'm trying to use annotations like this:

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;    
/**
 * Class Region
 * @package models
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="regions")
 */
class Region { ... }
```

In annotations i'm using not @Entity, i'm using @ORM\Entity() because IDE understanding what is that and making tips for me. But on this way Doctrine didnt see my classes. How i can to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The @ORM was added by Symfony which is why you see quite a bit of it.  The basic doctrine docs don't use it: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html I'm guessing your IDE has been setup to understand Symfony?  For non-Symfony Doctrine apps don't use the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue while creating the Doctrine configuration through the

```
Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration()
```

method. When you set its fifth parameter `$useSimpleAnnotationReader` to `false` you can use the name-spaced syntax the PhpStorm extension expects.